# Is this a bug with PHP array accessing?

Tags: php, arrays, data-access

I ran into this bug where an element of an array, if its index is the string "0", is inaccessible.

It's not a bug with unserialize, either, as this occurred in my code without invoking it.

```
$arr = unserialize('a:1:{s:1:"0";i:5;}');
var_dump($arr["0"]); //should be 5, but is NULL
var_dump($arr[0]);   //maybe this would work?  no. NULL
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  How do I access this element of the array?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it looks as though it is a bug, related to PHPs automatic conversion of strings to integers. More information is available here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43614

```
var_dump( $arr ); // => array(1) { ["0"]=>  int(5) } 
$arr2["0"]=5;
var_dump($arr2); // => array(1) { [0]=>  int(5) } 
print serialize($arr2); // a:1:{i:0;i:5;}
```

So it seems that older versions of PHP5 don't perform the string index to integer index conversion in unserialize.

This bug was reported in PHP 5.2.5, and is fixed in PHP 5.2.6 (see http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.6).

Comment: Doesn't say when it was fixed, but obviously before the version I'm using :)

Comment: Winner.  Thanks.

Now can we change the title back to "Is this a bug in PHP?" or something along those lines

Comment: Um... I'm using 5.2.5, and it's broken.  Do you mean it's fixed in 5.2.6?

Comment: how can bugs this fundamental be left out until version 5.2.6 ? that's just mind blowing

Comment: Sorry, I think 5.2.5 is the version the bug was reported against :(

Comment: They have to be found and reported to be fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

use var_dump on the structure to see how it's represented . maybe that will help. I was doing the same thing in Perl when I had problems like this with Data::Dumper

Comment: Sage advice. Investigate first!

Comment: I did that, but it is indeed a bug on php < 5.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code in your question yields

```
int(5)
```

Comment: Which version? I can reproduce John's behavior

Comment: "5.2.6-2+b1 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2"
on debian